# WordPress TinyMCE adding unwanted inline styles

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, inline-styles

I've been encountering a strange glitch in TinyMCE on WordPress; it will add it's own inline stylings to elements, particularly when I change the block type of it's parent. It appears to be due in part to having a custom editor stylesheet; as disabling it negates the problem.

Example case: I had a number of links, one per line, all with a special class on them (the class is configured to only apply to anchor tags). When I select that list of links and convert it to an unordered list, it applies inline styles to the links themselves, hard coding an (inaccurate) font size and adding a background colour to match that of the body.

I've added save filters that strip it out when being saved, but I'm baffled as to how it's doing this in the first place.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
var textContent = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
```

to get html content from editor and then save. It will give you filtered html content.

I was also facing the same issue but after using this everything is working fine.

Comment: How/where would I use this?